# MVC Owin Provider Key Change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin

I recently changed my MVC app from using

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication()
```

to

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions(){
ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"});
```

When I made this change it changed the provider key that was being returned by google. Resulting in any users already signed up being treated as a new user, Is there a way I can migrate the provider key or tell owin what provider key to use. I really don't want to take a change and manually run an update statement on my database to change the provider key.

Comment: no there is no way to fix that, the users authenticated that Client Id if you changed it they will need to authenticate the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was checking for the users email was already registered. If it was then I just added the additional login info to that user id.

```
user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
```